# Recursively Find and Modify the Data from Database

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have this kind of table (or data structure)

[image]

There is `parentIdeaId` that refers to the id in `ideas` table itself.

Here's my unstructured data (please bear in mind this is the existing data in the database, not data that is already as it is so I have to query this first under some condition)

```json
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "parentIdeaId": null
},{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "parentIdeaId": 1
},{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Title 3",
    "parentIdeaId": 2
}]
```

I also made a function to find the data (I'm using Prisma in my real code)

```js
function find({ id }) {
  return prisma.idea.findUnique({
    where: {
      id
    }
  });
}
```

And a function to find the children

```js
function responseIdeas({ parentIdeaId }) {
  return prisma.idea.findMany({
    where: {
      parentIdeaId
    }
  });
}
```

I want the data to be nested like this

```js
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "parentIdeaId": null,
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Title 2",
            "parentIdeaId": 1,
            "responses": [
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "title": "Title 3",
                    "parentIdeaId": 2,
                    "responses": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

So I made a recursive function

```js
async function detail({ id }) {
  const findChildren = async ({ id }) => {
    const idea = await find({ id });
    const responses = await responseIdeas({ parentIdeaId: id });
    if (responses.length !== 0) {
      const resolveResponses = await Promise.all(
        responses.map(async ({ id, ...rest }) => {
          const children = await findChildren({ id });
          return {
            id,
            ...rest,
            responses: children
          };
        })
      );
      return {
        ...idea,
        responses: resolveResponses
      };
    }
    return { ...idea };
  };

  return findChildren({ id });;
}
```

But it ended up being like this

```json
[{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title 1",
    "parentIdeaId": null,
    "responses": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Title 2",
            "parentIdeaId": 1,
            "responses": {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Title 2",
                "parentIdeaId": 1,
                "responses": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "title": "Title 3",
                        "parentIdeaId": 2,
                        "responses": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "title": "Title 3",
                            "parentIdeaId": 2
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

Where did I mess up? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map your responses, you only have to return `children`, not an object with `responses: children`.

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title 1",
    "parentIdeaId": null
},{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "parentIdeaId": 1
},{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Title 3",
    "parentIdeaId": 2
}];

function find({ id }) {
  return data.find((e) => e.id === id);
}

function responseIdeas({ parentIdeaId }) {
  return data.filter((e) => e.parentIdeaId == parentIdeaId);
}

async function detail({ id }) {
  const findChildren = async ({ id }) => {
    const idea = await find({ id });
    const responses = await responseIdeas({ parentIdeaId: id });
    if (responses.length !== 0) {
      const resolveResponses = await Promise.all(
        responses.map(async ({ id, ...rest }) => {
          const children = await findChildren({ id });
          return children; // <<---------------- modification
        })
      );
      return {
        ...idea,
        responses: resolveResponses
      };
    }
    return { ...idea };
  };

  return findChildren({ id });;
}

async function run() {
  const result = await detail({id: "1"});
  console.log(result);
}

run();
```

Comment: You're right. Thanks! Anyway, is my code good enough or do I have any space to simplify them?

Comment: I think it is definitely good enough. You can shorten the map operation like this: `responses.map(async ({ id, ...rest }) => findChildren({ id }))`